# Sub query in LLBL Gen Pro

Tags: sql, llblgenpro

I am new in LLBL gen pro, I have to write Sub query  using LLBL gen pro,but I am not getting any sample of how to write this.
This is the query I have to write, I know how to define fields, relations and predicate expression.

```
select UserId, TransactionId from 
UserTransaction
where TransactionId in
(
select  MaxId as TransactionId from
(SELECT MAX([TransactionId]) as MaxId, userid
FROM [UserTransaction]
group by userid) u1
inner join [UserTransaction] c2 on u1.MaxTId = c2.CCLeadTransactionId
where UserTypeId in (4,5)
)
```

and this is my table structure

```
UserTransaction
TransactionId userid UserTypeId
```

How can I write this query

```
  select  MaxId as TransactionId from
    (SELECT MAX([TransactionId]) as MaxId, userid
    FROM [UserTransaction]
    group by userid) u1
    inner join [UserTransaction] c2 on u1.MaxTId = c2.CCLeadTransactionId
    where UserTypeId in (4,5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic idea is to create inner query, that parent query can use

Sample code below (haven't tested it, might contain misspells)

```
var qf = new QueryFactory(); // create your create factory

var subFilterQuery = qf.Create()
    .Select(()=> UserTransaction.TransactionId.SetAggregateFunction(AggregateFunction.Max).ToValue<int>()) // select max transaction value
    // do joins, etc
    .GroupBy(UserTransactionFields.UserId);

var parentQuery = qf.Create()
    .Select(()=> new {
        UserId = UserTransactionFields.UserId.ToValue<int>(),
        TransactionId = UserTransactionFields.TransactionId.ToValue<int>(),
    })
    .Where(UserTransactionFields.TransactionId.In(subFilterQuery.ToScalar())); // use create query as filter
```